# Controlling Python Version from ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.1, geoprocessing, schema-architecture

I am writing a VB.net console application that calls ArcGIS Desktop 10.1 ArcToolbox geoprocessing tools from my code. Some of these tools use Python syntax and [I am encountering a problem](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/108230/arcgis-geoprocessing-and-32-64-bit-architecture-issue) that I suspect is caused by conflicting architectures. Is there a way to control which version of Python that ArcGIS uses?

- System: 64 bit Windows 8.1
- ArcGIS: 32 bit ArcGIS 10.1 Service Pack 1
- Python: Both 32 and 64 bit versions installed (latter from ESRI's background processing download)
- My App: 32 bit VB.net (not Any CPU) console application.

Answer (score 2):

See [this prior answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/609/will-arcgis-10-support-python-2-7-or-python-3-1#697). Each version of ArcGIS uses a specific version and architecture of Python and is hard-linked against it. Forcing an ArcObjects application to use an incompatible Python version will likely lead to a crash.